# SQL How can i exclude an entire group of data when only one member of the group meets criteria

Tags: sql

This is my first time asking a question on this site, so help me out if I'm missing information!

here is a simplified version of my current data set.

```
MajorCode Batch

 1. 1500  360715
 2. 6700  360715
 3. 6800  360715
 4. 1000  361098
 5. 1000  361098
 6. 1000  361098
 7. 1000  361211
 8. 1300  361211
 9. 1300  361211
```

I want to limit my results so that they only show when at least one Major Code per Batch is >= 4000.

So, for the example above I would only expect to have only the 3 records for `Batch #360715` be returned.

If this is possible, please let me know!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I Will be honest,  I do not know what that is.  I work in Showcase Query which allows me to look at data in IBM I series.  I am not a programmer, but have noticed that the answers given on this website work for what I usually am wanting to do, which I why I figured id it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL SERVER you can do this with a Sub Query like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #YourTable
WHERE Batch IN (SELECT DISTINCT BATCH 
                FROM #YourTable 
                WHERE MajorCode >= 4000)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  However, the results from your suggestion are not quite what I'd hoped for.  This appears to remove ALL records where Major Code is less than 4000.  If I have a Batch with Major Code records above and below 4000, I'd like to see all those records.  Only when all the records of a Batch are below 4000 do I not want to see any records of that batch.

Comment: This will return what you are asking for. The sub query gets any distinct Batch that has a value greater than 4000. Then it gets all major codes where it's in those batches.

Comment: Sorry!  That did do the trick!  thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Ok good. Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)  this or any answer that has solved your question by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.